# Json decode and filter a deep subarray of a 3d array using the values from a column in another 3d array

Tags: php, arrays, json, filtering, array-difference

I have two 3-dimensional arrays and I need to filter the deep (json-encoded) values of one array using the deep values of the other array.

My sample arrays:

```
$arr1 = [
       99 => [
           "number" => [1,3]
          ],
       88 => [
           "number" => [12,13,21]
           ]
    ];

$arr2 = [
           ["a"=>"01","b"=> '["01", "02", "03", "04"]'], 
           ["a"=>"02","b"=> '["11", "12", "13"]'],
           ["a"=>"03","b"=> '["21", "22", "23"]']
    ];
```

What I have tried:

```
foreach($arr1 as $val1){
    foreach($val1['number'] as $number){
        foreach($arr2 as $key => $val2){
            if(in_array($number,json_decode($val2['b']))){
                unset($arr2[$key ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to get the output :

```
 $arr2 = [
    ["a" => "01", "b" => ["02", "04"]],
    ["a" => "02", "b" => ["11"]],
    ["a" => "03", "b" => ["22", "23"]]
 ]
```

but the actual output I get is:

```
[]
```

Comment: why b is in string form array? ["a"=>"01","b"=> '["01", "02", "03", "04"]'],

Comment: it is from json [{"b": ["01", "02", "03", "04"]}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, I made it fancy for you.

```
$arr1 = [
       99 => [
           "number" => [1,3]
          ],
       88 => [
           "number" => [12,13,21]
           ]
    ];

$arr2 = [
           ["a"=>"01","b"=> '["01", "02", "03", "04"]'], 
           ["a"=>"02","b"=> '["11", "12", "13"]'],
           ["a"=>"03","b"=> '["21", "22", "23"]']
    ];

$numbers = preg_replace('/^(\d)$/', '0\1', array_merge(...array_column($arr1, 'number')));


array_walk($arr2, function(&$item)use($numbers){
        $item['b'] = array_diff(json_decode($item['b'], true),$numbers);
});


print_r($arr2);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 01
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 02
                    [3] => 04
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 02
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 03
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 22
                    [2] => 23
                )

        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50f3a9937a2b5ee284fc8088eff77a608eed78d9)

How it works.

Whenever you find your self in a situation where you need to compare one multi-dimensional array to another remember [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).  This allows you to pull out one column from the nested arrays. What that does is simplify one of the arrays and makes things a bit easier.

So lets go thought the above code function by function (in the order they are called):

```
array_column($arr1, 'number');
//Output: [[1,3],[12,13,21]]
```

This is not quite what we need and we can simplify it a bit more using [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [variadic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics) ( PHP >= 5.6) or variable length arguments. The `...` which has this effect:

```
 array_merge([1,3],[12,13,21]); //each nested array is a new argument
 //Output: [1,3,12,13,21]
```

Now we have something simple to work with, but there is still one issue.  This is that the values in the other list are strings with leading `0s` and in your expected output you retain these.  So to fix that we can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
preg_replace('/^(\d)$/', '0\1',[1,3,12,13,21])
//Output: ['01','03','12','13','21']

//non regex methods
//array_map(function($v){return strlen($v)>1?$v:"0$v";},[1,3,12,13,21])
//array_map(function($v){return str_pad($v,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);},[1,3,12,13,21])
```

The Regex `^(\d)$` simply matches elements with only `1` digit.  Then we capture that and use it in the replacement `0\1`. The `\1` transfers that number we captured into that "replacement" string.  This effectively adds a leading `0` on items with `1` digit, which is what we need.  There is a few non-regex ways you could do this but none of them are as "pretty", see the above non-regex example.

I will assume [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) needs no introduction.

Then we simply loop over them ([array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) in this case), and use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to compare the 2 arrays.  This return only the items in array1 that are not in array2.  So for this

```
 //loop1
 array_diff(["01", "02", "03", "04"],['01','03','12','13','21']);
 //Output: ["02", "04"]

 //loop2
 array_diff(["11", "12", "13"],['01','03','12','13','21']);
 //Output: ["11"]

 //loop3
 array_diff(["21", "22", "23"],['01','03','12','13','21']); 
 //Output: ["22", "23"]
```

Then because were [updating by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) `function(&$item)` in our closure, we are all done.

Yea that was fun!  Unfortunately I don't see a way to do this in `1` line, however what I have is essentially `2` lines so that's not so bad...

Hope that helps explain it.

**Update**

I lied, I figured out how to do it in `1` line (**165 bytes**):

```
  array_walk($arr2,function(&$i,$k,$n){$i['b']=array_diff(json_decode($i['b'],true),$n);},preg_filter('/^(\d)$/','0\1',array_merge(...array_column($arr1,'number'))));
```

To do this (I remembered) you can pass additional arguments into `array_map` so that is what I did.  This avoids the assignment issues with the `use` statement.  It's like any function you cannot set a default that is the result of another function call.

```
 //for example this doesn't work
 function(&$item)use($numbers = preg_replace(...)){ ... }
```

But this does (additional argument is `$n` in this case):

```
 array_walk($arr2,function(&$i,$k,$n){....},preg_replace(...));
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/23102bac49940ec19689c47185147730c342d21e)

**Summery**

Essentially what I am doing, is taking one of the arrays and making it the same format as what we want to compare it to.  That way, we simplify the problem, instead of just throwing a ton of code at it.  It's always better to reduce complexity, granted this is "complex" if you don't know what these functions do on an intimate level.  But I do know this so it's not so hard to read for me.

Cheers!

Comment: That's now a nice answer since there is explanations :)

Comment: It was always a nice answer, explaining just means that I am nice.... lol

Comment: I even linked all the functions to the PHP documentation too.  Because I feel extra nice right now.... `\(o.0)/`

Comment: Sure, it was a nice break from all the jQuery I was doing last night.... :)

Comment: I like everything about the first snippet.  Trivially, I might suggest using `'/^\d$/', '0$0'`.  The later snippet that shows everything in one line should not be used because it is recalculating the blacklist array for each row of the second array -- not good for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are unsetting the whole `unset($arr2[$key])` if you find something in `$arr2[$key]['b']` that why you are getting an empty array. You want to `unset($arr2[$key]['b'][$someIndexToRemove])` which is actually not possible since `['b']` is serialized

To simplify your task I suggest you to decode first your json, like this in example :

```
foreach($arr2 as $key => $val)
    $arr2[$key]['b'] = json_decode($val['b']);
```

Now you can treat directly your array as is, like this in example :

```
<?php
$arr1 = [
       99 => [
           "number" => [1,3]
          ],
       88 => [
           "number" => [12,13,21]
           ]
    ];

$arr2 = [
           ["a"=>"01","b"=> '["01", "02", "03", "04"]'], 
           ["a"=>"02","b"=> '["11", "12", "13"]'],
           ["a"=>"03","b"=> '["21", "22", "23"]']
    ];

foreach($arr2 as $key => $val)
    $arr2[$key]['b'] = json_decode($val['b']);

foreach($arr1 as $val1){
    foreach($val1['number'] as $number) { // Loop every 'number' in $arr1
        foreach($arr2 as $key => $val2) {
            foreach($val2['b'] as $key2 => $val3) { // Loop every values in 'b'
                if($number == intval($val3)) { // compare against an int ('b' contains strings)
                    unset($arr2[$key]['b'][$key2]); // remove the unwanted value
                    $arr2[$key]['b'] = array_values($arr2[$key]['b']); // reset the numeric indexes
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($arr2);
```

Output :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(2) "01"
    ["b"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "02"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "04"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(2) "02"
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "11"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(2) "03"
    ["b"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "22"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "23"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think i need to add foreach($arr2 as $key => $val)
    $arr2[$key]['b'] = json_encode($val['b']); to convert it back to json, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, in my own professional project, I'd be very likely to craft something virtually identical to @ArtisticPhoenix's first snippet.

To provide a bit more diversity in the answers on this page, I'll offer an equivalent snippet which uses classic loops instead of functional-style iterator.

Explanation of the task:

1. The first array needs have its `number` column data flattened/merged AND all of the numbers should be zero-padded to make swift identical comparisons against the other array.
2. The second array needs to have its `b` data json decoded, filtered, and re-indexed to achieve the desired result.

Points of difference between my snippet and @ArtisticPhoenix's first snippet:

1. I "destructure" the subarray data inside both of the `foreach()` loops because I know that I only need access to specific data sets.
2. I am using associative keys while populating the `$blacklist` array to ensure that each value is unique.
3. I am using the "null coalescing assignment operator" (`??=`) to ensure that `str_pad()` is not called if processing a numeric value that is already in the `$blacklist` array.
4. I am calling `array_values()` after filtering with `array_diff()` so that the subarray elements are re-indexed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/F00KL))

```
$blacklist = [];
foreach ($arr1 as ['number' => $numbers]) {
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $blacklist[$n] ??= str_pad($n, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}
foreach ($arr2 as ['b' => &$b]) {
    $b = array_values(array_diff(json_decode($b, true), $blacklist));
}

var_export($arr2);
```